# Proof for X $\setminus$ (A $\cap$ B) = (X $\setminus$ A) $\cup$ (X $\setminus$ B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am confused about the proof for $X$ $\setminus$ $($$A$ $\cap$ $B$$)$ = $($$X$ $\setminus$ $A$$)$ $\cup$ $($$X$ $\setminus$ $B$$)$.

The proof states that suppose $x$ $\in$ $X$ $\setminus$ $($$A$ $\cap$ $B$$)$, then $x$ $\in$ $X$ and $x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\cap$ $B$, but I am not understanding the logic behind how it follows that $x$ $\notin$ $A$ or $x$ $\notin$ $B$.

My understanding is that if $x$ $\notin$ $A$ $\cap$ $B$, then $x$ $\notin$ $A$ and $x$ $\notin$ $B$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NRJQn1AMik8

Comment: $x \not \in A \cap B$ if and only if $x \not \in A$ or $x\not \in B$.

Comment: @mathbeing: all I meant to suggest is that you consider expanding a bit on your answer...You had a good start, and I'm sorry if my comment sounded intimidating. (I've had a long day!) Anyway, I hope you consider expanding on your answer, because I think you were/are on the right track. Indeed, I deleted the comment I left below your answer.

Comment: With these proofs it usually helps to draw a picture.

Comment: @Dunham I understand now. Thank you all for your input!